# Is it safe to storage materials inside a hand made cave?

Tags: astroneer

I was playing coop with some friends and we were just starting a new game. As we didn't have Research Station yet, we started placing all the *research items* right next to our Habitat.

Surprisingly (not really) a storm came and all of our items flew away. As a fix for this, my friends created a small cave and we are now storaging research items and such there (also some materials not needed).

So far, storms don't affect us or the items inside the cave but, is this a valid solution forever or could we lose everything by any other kind of disaster?

Answer (score 2):

I do this myself and never had issue with it.
Also I've seen a couple YouTubers doing so in let's play and tutorial.

Items never disappeared from it and never flew away either.

It is perfectly safe to use this as storage method, at least at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

do not do this the items will glitch through the ground into underground caves

Comment: I'd say a glitch is something we can't predict, the storage units could also glitch out and I could lose everything from them for no reason. Anyways, I'm asking for some disasters designed by the developers, not by their mistakes :)

Comment: @Alex If one thing is more likely to cause glitches than others, I don't see why you wouldn't want to be warned about it.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I of course want, for sure, and I appreciate it, but glitches will be fixed (I hope), so I prefer to know if any intentional "thing" will make them dissapear

Comment: Yes it's better to know the difference because something designed likely /won't/ go away and we'll have to look out for it. For example in Skyrim it was /designed/ that chests in "the wild" now have a respawning inventory, making them unsafe for storage of items of any kind. Only "owned" chests will preserve your items. At first people thought this was just a bug, because in past games containers never reset their inventory automatically. So they kept trying it, "hoping" that the bug wouldn't happen...but the "feature" /would/ always happen so RIP their stuff lol

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites agree. *I like your profile desc lol*

Comment: @Alex Thanks ;) I can only imagine the theoretical potential of this site (group of sites) if only we could all kindly leave our egos at the door...but alas, the human species thinks it needs the ego for literally /everything/ so that won't happen!